# datepicker dynamic date button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a custom dynamical date extra button in jquery datepicker. But it doesnt work... Error in my code?

```
$(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "2014:2034",
        showButtonPanel: true,
        beforeShow: function (input) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var buttonPane = $(input)
                    .datepicker("widget")
                    .find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");

                var btn = $('<button class="ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" type="button">CSA</button>');
                btn.unbind("click")
                    .bind("click", function () {
                        //$.datepicker._clearDate(input);
                        //alert('custom text');
                        $(input).datepicker("hide");
                        var date = new Date();
                        date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 6);
                        $(input).val(date.getFullYear() + '-'
                            date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDate());

                    });


                btn.appendTo(buttonPane);

            }, 1);
        }
    });
});
```

the goal is to add a button today + 6 months

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a +

Change this:

```
       $(input).val(date.getFullYear() + '-'
       date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDate());
```

To this:

```
       $(input).val(date.getFullYear() + '-' +
       date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDate());
```

Also do not forget that Javascript moth is 0 based, so if you want to add 6 month to today's date you need to add 7 to current month, meaning, instead of:

```
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 6);
```

use:

```
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 7);
```

See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ME9Zw/)

Comment: I have made you a fiddle and updated my answer with it.